# How to generate mhtml file in C++?

Tags: c++, html, mime

I want to generate multimedia documents(so called `MIME`) defined by Html.
So I can pack associated files (e.g. htm, images…) in `a single mhtml (MIME) file here`(like: [mime_example.doc](http://sebsauvage.net/wiki/doku.php?do=export_code&id=word_document_generation&codeblock=16)).
But I only got `php implementation here`: [A basic MIME 1.0 class helper](http://sebsauvage.net/wiki/doku.php?id=word_document_generation#ideas_worth_pondering)
(in the "A basic MIME 1.0 class helper" section)
And `the method to generate` the mhtml file:

```
header('Content-Type: application/msword');
header('Content-disposition: filename=mydocument.doc')
$doc = New mime10class();
$doc->addFile('mydocument.htm','text/html; charset="utf-8"','Hello, world !');
$doc->addFile('subdir\anotherfile.htm','text/html; charset="utf-8"','Hi there.');
echo $doc->getFile();
```

**But how to implement this using c++?**
(Helpful link: [MIME Encapsulation of Aggregate Documents, such as HTML (MHTML)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2557))

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/content/renderer/mhtml_generator.cc

Comment: You can always pipe correctly formatted text into a string(stream) ...

Comment: @aleguna: But I do not want to make a chromium.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, the point is to implement the Encoding.

Comment: @Rubby, You asked how to do it in C++, I gave you a link to C++ implementation. You can easily extract the part that generates MHTML from chomium/webkit. Problem solved?

Comment: @aleguna, too difficult for me:(

Comment: @Rubby: So what are you asking for? how to implement that encoding? I am sure there are standards that describe it. Or are you asking us to find a library that already does it for you?

Comment: Asking for lists of tutorials, solutions, libraries etc. is discouraged (see, e.g. [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139008/are-questions-asking-for-tutorials-allowed)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether is a separate opensource library which do this, but https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX it convert PDF to html and it got option to  pack associated files (e.g. htm, images…) in a single html file (by default it does not), may be you can use code from this project as its opensource!